# $error returns invalid array when using custom validator

Tags: angularjs

I am using a textbox to show a date field. I have written a validator to check the if the date is correct or not. When I enter a valid value in the date textbox the validator returns true But the form.$error still contains valid=false for that element.

Has anybody faced this problem? What am I doing wrong here?

```
ngModel.$validators.invalidDate = function(modelValue,viewValue){
return handleValidation(modelValue,viewValue,function(value){
                               return true;
                           });
                       };
```

Comment: Can you post more code or (ideally) a plunker/fiddle? Not sure this is verifiable with what has been provided.

Comment: Show code for `handleValidation` function.